# CANVAS! Eneter the Bermuda Circle

Tags: canvas, click, mouseevent

I'm try to make the canvas draw a circle, when the user creates a click event, I just created something using the method I used in the code below, and here it is: http://codepen.io/collection/XKpoba/

Now I'm trying to make a simple circle using the same method, but my x and y variables are showing up undifined, even thought I've got them clearly declared before use. I'm figuring that since the beginPath() ans storke() is a method, that might be the problem. I don't know how to feed information to them about the outer scope. I'm at a loss. here is the codepen: http://codepen.io/JermaineBerkley/pen/WQNgbL

and here's the code:

```
window.onload = init();

function init(){
  this.canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  this.context = canvas.getContext('2d');

  return canvas, context;
}

function circle(){
  this.init = init();
  this.radius = 20;

  canvas.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false); 

  function clickHandler (event){

    this.x = event.clientX;
    this.y = event.clientY;

    context.beginPath();
    context.strokeStyle = 'DeepSkyBlue';

    context.arc(x, y, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.stroke();

    return clickHandler;
  }
  var click = clickHandler();
}
circle();
```

Comment: You're doing `circle()` immediately even before the window is fully loaded so your canvas references aren't initted yet. The cure is to wrap your code inside `<script> window.onload = function(){ ...all code... }; </script>`.

Comment: thanks for the help mark!